# Is it ok to post several smaller, simpler questions in hopes of being able to answer a large, more complex question?

Tags: discussion

I have a complex question I've asked on DA. This the question I asked: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36127/how-would-i-load-a-node-into-the-footer-of-a-view-depending-on-the-image-clicked. In order to try and find a solution to this question, I've asked several, smaller and simpler questions in order to find the solution to that specific question.

- [How to customize the url of a field in views?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36515/how-to-customize-the-url-a-field-links-to-using-the-jcarousel-format)
- [How do you load a node inside of another node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36504/how-do-you-load-a-node-inside-of-another-node) (This question got 2 down votes. I flagged for moderator attention to able to fix/improve the question but got no response.)
- [How to do you modify the URL created by a module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36221/how-to-append-a-node-id-to-a-url-from-a-taxonomy-term)

Although I know the complex question is appropriate because it fits all the criteria of a good question, I'm not sure that asking the other smaller questions is good workflow for the site.

Is this the correct way to approach questions/situations of this manner?
Should the simpler/smaller questions be asked (and not the complex one) in hopes that the complex question/situation be resolved through the single, simpler questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd stick with the smaller questions to be honest. The larger, more complex questions are far more likely to be specific to a certain scenario that you're working to, and could easily be considered too localised (one of the options given when voting to close a question).

One of the mantras of this fine network is that any question asked should be useful to future visitors. Breaking your problems down into more manageable bites (and preferably abstracting them to the generic problem at hand) will help to make sure that ethos struggles on.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the correct way to approach questions/situations of this manner?

If you can split a complex task in three sub-tasks, then asking three questions is better. As Clive said, the chance the questions are useful to other users is higher than in the case of a single complex question.

> I flagged for moderator attention to able to fix/improve the question but got no response.

Actually, you got [an answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/5740):

> You shouldn't flag a question for moderator attention because you received a down vote. That being said your question is very unclear - border line not a real question. It helps to use What/How/etc.

Flags are not for any bi-directional communication; they should be used where there is a post that needs moderation attention, such as in the case a post is spam, rude, offensive, or an answer should rather be a comment.

If you want to know how to improve a post, or which type of questions you should ask, you can ask a question here on the meta site.